# Восстановление БД из бэкапа

Tags: sql, sql-server

На тестовом сервере восстанавливаю backup базы данных для различных манипуляций. Если это делать при помощи sql management studio тыкая в кнопки и ставя галочки все проходит удачно, долго но удачно. Если при помощи того же management studio создается запрос

```
Restore database [database_name]
FROM DISK = 'file_path'
```

то после 3 часов восстановления мне надоедает ждать и я завершаю запрос сам. И наконец если тот же самый запрос выполнять при помощи sqlcmd например или иного скрипта допустим powershell, то после 5-6 минут выполнения падает с ошибкой таймаута. Отсюда два вопроса из-за чего падает при выполнении через скрипт и можно ли как то ускорить процесс восстановления.
Версия сервера **Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP3-GDR) (KB3194721) - 11.0.6248.0 (X64)**

Ошибка с которой падает скрипт. Скрипт написан на powershell.

```
Исключение при вызове "ExecuteReader" с "0" аргументами: "Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation 
or the server is not responding.
Резервное копирование или восстановление прервано."
C:\scripts\RestoreBackup.ps1:53 знак:31
+                               $objReader = $SqlCmd.ExecuteReader()
+                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlException

Невозможно вызвать метод для выражения со значением NULL.
C:\scripts\RestoreBackup.ps1:54 знак:38
+                               while ($objReader.read()) {
+                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Невозможно вызвать метод для выражения со значением NULL.
C:\scripts\RestoreBackup.ps1:57 знак:33
+                                 $objReader.close()
+                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Comment: Начните с включения [Instant File Initialization](https://www.brentozar.com/blitz/instant-file-initialization/)

Comment: А какая версия SQL Server-а? Добавьте к вопросу результат `SELECT @@VERSION`. Я правильно понимаю, что `select instant_file_initialization_enabled from sys.dm_server_services` равно `Y` для сервера?

Comment: Да все правильно понимаете.

Comment: В SSMS - добавьте STATS = 1, будет выводить прогресс

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь это поможет проанализировать запрос в пределах management studio.